# Plot chronological data separated into columns on one graph

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet of temperature vs time with multiple columns representing each day:
[image]

Is there a way in which I can plot all of the columns of temperature data as one continuous line?

Comment: Could you post a link to your spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

Plot a new column, that has this calculation:

```
=FILTER({B2:B;C2:C;...},LEN({B2:B;C2:C;...}))
```

*replace the 3 dots with the ranges of the other columns*